# .png images wont load after switching site to HTTPS

Tags: ssl, joomla, https

I installed an SSL Certificate which required me to switch all HTTP Links over to HTTPs links. I did this by downloading all site files (including the database) and did a find/replace, thus replacing all http:// with https://  then I uploaded the new site files (and .sql file) to the server. And everything appeared to be working. Except that .png images wont load in any browser.

I can't even pull up the image by typing in the direct link in the address bar (with or without the https). Previously the images worked fine, they now just show the red X.

Any ideas on what's going on and how can I fix it?
The site is built with Joomla 2.5. You can see it here: https://www.detourjournal.com/ (Note the two .png images in the footer that are not loading)

Comment: When you attempt to go directly to the image URLs, the response is empty. It seems most likely that the file is missing, but could also be that Joomla can't encode the PNG on HTTPS. You could test the latter by trying a new PNG image somewhere on the site.

Comment: The files are definitely there (I've triple checked). My thought is that it can't be a joomla issue since, as you've said, going Directly to the image URL doesn't work either (and this should bypass any joomla involvement).  I think it has to be something related to my server (Apache-openSSL) not being able to process .png with https.  does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not your Joomla! setup, for starters it doesn't appear to be Joomla! redirecting calls to SSL in normal pages and it doesn't affect direct file URL for images this way.

You appear to have configured your server to force `https` (possibly via `.htaccess`).

It's also not specific to PNG files as your logo, [`/images/stories/logo2.png`](https://www.detourjournal.com/images/stories/logo2.png) is being served without a problem. The same goes for the PNG's in VirtueMart e.g. [the close label](https://www.detourjournal.com/detourjournal/components/com_virtuemart/assets/images/facebox/closelabel.png).

Looking at the header for those images the sizes don't match what is being returned... so it's most likely corrupt images cause Apache to bork.

Comment: Awesome! It was corrupt images (sort of). The .png files that weren't working were saved as layered/editable .png files instead of flattened .png. I changed that setting, re-saved them and now it's working fine! I've got a related issue, but I'll start a new thread for that. Thank you!!

Comment: but I have to ask, why did the layered .png's work before the change to https? how would that affect the images? (and yes .htaccess is redirecting URLs to HTTPs, is wasn't before)

Comment: Not sure, probably the way the image preview and layers are separated within the file format that doesn't survive. Apache probably chokes in http just after the PNG's files preview, possibly with a partial chunk loaded… so probably something buried fairly deep in the whole file transfer encryption process.